# Displaying a column total in a report

Tags: civireport

Is there a way to display a column total when viewing a report?

Specifically, we are wanting to run reports on contribution line items and quickly see the contribution line item total.

When you do Find Contributions, it displays the total, # completed, and average. Due to how we have our data set up, we need to use the line item report to view all of our donations; we can't use Find Contributions. I'm looking for a way for staff to quickly see donation totals from those line item reports.

Interestingly, if you run a line item report (http://example.com/civicrm/report/price/lineitem) and you don't have any sort criteria, it will display a total at the bottom, but if you enable sorting, that total goes away.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Pivot Report extension at 
https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-pivot-reports 
and 
the ReportPlus extension at
https://civicrm.org/extensions/reportplus . 
Both should give you a way to produce the report you want, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. For some reason, the Pivot Report won't load the Contribution report. The progress bar goes beyond 100% and never stops rising. The ReportPlus contribution reports don't have Line Item fields as column or filter options. The report I'm successfully using is http://example.com/civicrm/report/price/lineitem. Due to how we have our data set up, I need to display and filter on those Line Item fields.